# IE7 compatible twentyeleven

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven, browser-compatibility

I installed a site with the stock twentyeleven theme but it looks terrible in IE6 and has many small problems in IE7. I am ready to give up on IE6 but not on IE7 yet but wouldn't like to rewrite a whole theme from scratch just to fix IE7.

Is there a port of twentyeleven that supports these 2 browsers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to know that twenty eleven theme is in HTML5 and IE6, IE7 doesn't supports HTML5 (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html5.html)

Secondly if you are having a menu problem in IE 7, then there is a fix available which I found on some website

`#branding #searchform {
display: none;
position: absolute;
right: 7.6%;
text-align: right;
top: 3.8em;
}`

Comment: Well this is what I wanted to point out. Since it's HTML 5 my "compatible with IE7" theme means that the theme would be a re-write of twentyeleven in XHTML 1.1

Since it isn't a fancy theme I wonder why they chose HTML 5.